# Python doesn't find Pyomo

Tags: python, python-import, pyomo

I'm stumped on why Python won't import pyomo.  I can find the directory and see it is installed:

```
234:pyomo user$ pip show pyomo
Name: Pyomo
Version: 5.1.1
Summary: Pyomo: Python Optimization Modeling Objects
Home-page: http://pyomo.org
Author: William E. Hart
Author-email: wehart@sandia.gov
License: BSD
Location: /Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: appdirs, PyUtilib, six, ply
```

And the directory is at the front of my $PYTHONPATH:

```
>>> import sys; print sys.path
['', '/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyomo', '/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/Users/user/anaconda/pkgs', '/Users/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',  ... ]
```

But I still can't import pyomo:

```
>>> import pyomo.environ
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pyomo.environ
>>> from pyomo.environ import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pyomo.environ
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: does importing pyomo work?

Comment: I get the same ImportError for `import pyomo` Moreover there is no __init__.py file in the pyomo directory, so I wouldn't expect that to work anyway.

Comment: There actually is a `__init__.py` file for version 5.1.1. I can import pyomo and pyomo.environ. Just verifying. You sure that you're running that in the same python interpreter as the one you're `pip show`ing at?

Comment: that was it!  Somehow I had gotten my user/bin python in front of anaconda in $PATH.  Thank you.

Comment: I'll post the answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you're trying to import from the same interpreter you're using when you're running `pip show`.

When these things happen (and they tend to), it's always good to to try and run `which python` (assuming you're on linux/osx) to verify that it is the python you're intending to use.

Answer (score 1):

I would uninstall it via pip,

```
pip uninstall pyomo
```

and then reinstall it via conda.

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyomo
```

Comment: Add some more details

Comment: I mean, there is no way we can figure out why it is not importing pyomo, in a system, which pyomo is already installed. So what would be the best option is to reinstall it. But I find conda better than pip. Just from the personal experience with both. I ended up less problems using conda over pip.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have pandas installed. If not,

```
pip install pandas
```

then

```
pip install pyomo
```

this works for me