# Why does 'pip show pyomo' list a different directory than 'which pyomo'?

Tags: python, linux, bash, pip, pyomo

This is more of a general question about the nature of linux, pip, and virtual environments.

For context: I've been setting up python and pyomo to run some optimization problems on a wsl Ubuntu 20.04 installation on top of my Windows 10 environment. I've set up a virtual environment using venv and everything runs fine from both Visual Studio Code as well as Bash; however, initially while running my script via the python terminal in VS Code, I ran into an issue where my python environment couldn't find my pyomo module. Using [this S.O. thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42724173/python-doesnt-find-pyomo), I was able to figure out that I was calling the wrong interpreter within VS Code since I was in a venv, and I changed it successfully - and I am now able to execute my code from both a Python terminal as well as Bash.

However, while doing that exercise I realized that I was getting different paths for my pyomo installation depending on which command I used to search for the installation, which puzzled me, and I figured this could be a learning opportunity to better understand Linux.

When I run pip show pyomo inside my venv, I get the following, as expected:

[image]

Compared to when I run `pip show pyomo` outside of venv:
[image]

So far so good, since from what I understand the purpose of creating a venv is that you will be able to install packages, modules, and dependencies independent of your global environment. However, when I run `which pyomo` and `whereis pyomo`, I get different directories than with `pip show pyomo` outside of my venv, as seen below: [image]

When I navigate to each directory, I notice that in `/usr/local/bin/` there is a pyomo executable, whereas when I go to `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages` there is a pyomo directory. I notice that this also occurs within the venv, so my question is, what is `which pyomo` doing that is different from `pip show pyomo`? **Is the answer as simple as one command showing the installation directory and another showing the executable path? Is this normal behavior that I should expect with all python packages, and if so, why is the pyomo executable located outside of the pyomo directory?**

For example, when I try the same exercise with pandas, I get the following, where `which` and `whereis` don't show anything, and indeed I can't find a pandas executable in the `/usr/local/bin/` directory:
[image]

I get even more confused when I do the same thing for python3 and I get the following, where there are executables located at both `/usr/local/bin/` and `/usr/local/lib/` [image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pandas is not a command, it's just the name of the package. You can't run `pandas` on the command line.

Comment: Pyomo apparently has an executable called `pyomo`, *and* a package with the same name. Pip shows the package, `which` the executable. `which pyomo` or `whereis pyomo` do not list packages, they list executables.

Answer (score 0):

Most Python packages do not have executables.  The one in `/usr/local/lib` is probably just an empty shell that does something like `import pyomo` / `pyomo.run()`, and it will pick up whatever the current Python environment is.